# Is there an Intercal mode for GNU Emacs?

Tags: emacs, esoteric-languages, intercal

I cannot find an [Intercal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercal) mode for GNU Emacs. Is there one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course.  After all, without it you could hardly program productively...  And it's packaged [by Debian](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/intercal/filelist) (and derivatives). :)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see it's part of the C-INTERCAL distribution. Not sure how I missed that! Thanks Matthew.

Comment: that same distribution comes with one.  Try `info c-intercal` (language) and `info ick` (compiler).

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: I think you must mean `C-h i` followed by `g (ick)`?

Comment: Also, wouldn't being unable to program productively without the Emacs mode be a good argument *against* it, given the purpose of INTERCAL?

Comment: @SamB, I never said you could program productively *with* it. :)

Comment: To be productive, just upgrade to VisualIronINTERCAL#.Net++/CLI-2023 (ANTSY X3.53-2022, ECZEMA-374:2023, ICEHOLE/EEK-60374:2023)